# Чем отличаются public class от class?

Tags: ооп, классы, php

Доброго времени суток!

У меня возник вопрос по php ООП. Чем отличаются public class от class?

Comment: вы путаете теплое с мягким. public - модификатор доступа для членов класса. А "просто функции" к ООП вообще отношения не имеют

Comment: я конечно с php знаком весьма посредственно, но по-моему конструкция типа public class для этого языка [ошибочна][1].

[1]:http://ideone.com/VzKZwd

Comment: модификаторы доступа в php есть только у свойств и методов класса и интерфейса. public class - это уже Java, ActionScript...

Comment: >видел в нескольких уроках такое, и на форумах когда предоставляли код с просьбой о помощи.

я думаю, компилятор/интерпретатор знает синтаксис php лучше, чем авторы уроков и те, кто просят помощи на форумах. Во всяком случае, в приведенном мной примере public class является ошибкой

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что касается public class и class в PHP можно только class, если это просто пример и вопрос также касается

```
public function boo(){}
```

и

```
function boo(){}
```

внутри класса, то 2ой вариант устаревший, когда ООП в PHP было плохо реализовано и отсутствие модификатора доступа подразумевало public, сейчас так оставлено для совместимости, модификатор можно опускать (будет public), но не рекомендуется.

Comment: свои 5 копеек :) - "...было плохо реализовано...", "...модификатора доступа подразумевало public..." не то что OOP было хорошо или плохо реализовано (о его текущей реализации тоже немало холиваров) просто его реализация была такой, что многое было сделано по другому в том числе не существовало public, privat или protected членов класса